# On change input value not change in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have ajax. in

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $('.remaining').val(item.arrears)
});
```

`.remaining` input value not change on change. Anyone know how to do
this. I am new in JQuery. Below you can find the JQuery I am using.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("select[name='student_detail_id']").change(function() {
      var student_detail_id = $(this).val();
      console.log(student_detail_id);
      var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
      $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo url('admin/remaining_fee') ?>",
          method: 'POST',
          data: { student_detail_id: student_detail_id, _token: token },
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".remaining").each(function() {
                $(this).find('input').not(':first').remove();
            });

            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                 $('.remaining').val(item.arrears)

            });
          }
      });
  });
  </script>

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="email">Remaining</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control remaining" name="" id="" required="" Readonly /></div>
```

I want on change select val() change.

Comment: thats now how it should be done. first what you are using `$(this).find('input').not(':first').remove();` for?

Comment: and can you show us the `.remining` in a sample html?

Comment: @MishelParkour actually i copy from any website same. so i use. by the way this is not work. i think.

Comment: @MishelParkour check edit.

Comment: html please. give us html code which contains `.remaining`

Comment: Setting a value with JavaScript does not trigger event listeners. `$('.remaining').val(item.arrears).trigger('change');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you replace this:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
     $('.remaining').val(item.arrears)
});
```

with this:

```
  $("select[name='student_detail_id']").change(function() {
      var student_detail_id = $(this).val();
      console.log(student_detail_id);
      var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
      $.ajax({
          url: "<?php echo url('admin/remaining_fee') ?>",
          method: 'POST',
          data: { student_detail_id: student_detail_id, _token: token },
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".remaining").each(function() {
                // here we empty the container to make it ready to add items
                $('.inputContainer').html('');
                //$(this).find('input').not(':first').remove();
            });

            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                 //here we create an element
                 const $input = $('<input />')
                   .addClass('form-control remaining')
                   .attr('name','remaining')
                   .attr('id', 'remaining_'+i)
                   .attr('type', 'text')
                   .attr('readonly', 'readonly')
                   .val(item.arrears)

                 // here we append it into container
                 $('.inputContainer').append($input);

              });

          }
      });
  });
```

and html something like:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="email">Remaining</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control remaining" name="" id="" required="" Readonly />
 <div class="inputContainer" >

 </div>
</div>
```

This is how you add an element with jQuery. and then you can do `$('#container').append($element)`

Comment: Great. can we remove 
<input type="text" class="form-control remaining" name="" id="" required="" Readonly /> Or
<div class="inputContainer" > ??

Comment: why you want to remove them? yes you can but you need to somehow tell jquery where to put those newly added items. easiest way is to have a container element (the way I showed it in my code) you can remove the first input if you dont want it to be there